# getting listed date between two dates excluding weekends in mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, database, winforms

I'm trying to make a program using c# winform. I am strugggling with handling database. I am trying to get all the dates between two dates excluding weekends.
For example result should be like this:

2019-07-01 ~ 2019-07-10

2019-07-01

2019-07-02

2019-07-03

2019-07-04

2019-07-05

2019-07-08

2019-07-09

2019-07-10

2019-07-06 and 2019-07-07 shouldn't be printed because it is saturday and sunday.

Trying to get date from LAB_SDATE and LAB_EDATE from the table shown below.

I want to add listed dates in to another Table.
[image]

Comment: Does this dates are stored in table?

Comment: There are two ways to handle this. Either use a calendar table or use the built in function [`DAYOFWEEK()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek) to filter the results.  
Depending on the size of the table and indexes it has, a calendar table solution might have a better performance than a `dayofweek` based solution.

Comment: added up an image to explain more plz help

Comment: You are mixing too many problems. Are you having problems with reading the database, or with removing the weekends, or with displaying the results in winforms ? like @KacperTurowski says, let us know what you tried.

Comment: I want to insert listed dates between two dates excluding weekends into another table

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT datecolumn 
FROM table 
WHERE WEEKDAY(datecolumn)<5;
```

Comment: i do not have datecolumn